# Custom grep in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I finished the Ruby chapter in [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](http://pragprog.com/titles/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks). It tries to make you familiar with the core concepts of several languages rather quickly. Dutifully I did all exercises, but most likely they can be improved to be more Ruby-like.

> Write a simple grep that will print the lines of a file having any occurrences of a phrase anywhere in that line (in my example 'bleh'). Include line numbers.

```
File.open( 'grepFile.txt', 'r' ) do |file|
  lines = []
  line_number = 1
  file.readlines.each do |line|
    lines[line_number] = line
    line_number += 1
  end
  lines.each_index do |i|  
    line = lines[i]
    puts "line #{i.to_s}: #{line}" if line =~ /bleh/
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
File.open( 'grepFile.txt', 'r' ) do |file|
  lines = []
  line_number = 1
  file.readlines.each do |line|
    lines[line_number] = line
    line_number += 1
  end
  lines.each_index do |i|  
    line = lines[i]
    puts "line #{i.to_s}: #{line}" if line =~ /bleh/
  end
end
```

`file.readlines.each` should be `file.each_line`, which will do the same thing (iterate over all the lines) without building an array (and reading the whole file into memory) first. Also instead of keeping track of the `line_number` manually, you should just use `each_with_index`. Though actually if you want to append to the end of the array, you actually shouldn't use an index at all, but use `<<` or `push` instead (if you want the indices to start at 1, you can just insert a `nil` element first).

That being said if all you want is to read the file into an array, you could just do `lines = file.readlines` without any loop (or possible `[nil] + file.readlines`, so that it keeps starting at 1, but I'd rather add 1 to the line number when printing instead of copying the whole array).

Further you can use the methods `File.readlines` or `File.foreach` instead of `File.open` + `File#readlines` or `File.open` + `File#each_line` respectively.

Then when you iterate over `lines` you should use `each_with_index` rather than `each_index`, so you don't have to do `lines[i]` to get at the value.

As a last note, it's unnecessary to call `to_s` on an object in `#{}` - ruby does that automatically.

---

However the whole approach seems needlessly complicated to me. I don't see why you need to build up an array at all. I'd just iterate over the lines once and output them directly. This in addition to being much shorter also has the advantage, that the program runs in `O(1)` space (assuming the maximum line length is constant) rather than reading the whole file into memory.

```
File.foreach('grepFile.txt').each_with_index do |line, i|
  puts "line #{i}: #{line}" if line =~ /bleh/
end
```

And of course instead of `'grepFile.txt'` and `/bleh/`, you should be using `ARGV[1]` and `Regexp.new(ARGV[0])`, as it makes no sense to hardcode these values.

Comment: Nice! I was looking for a way to also get the index, but was looking in the wrong place (an overload of each which now I know isn't really supported). The whole reason for the array was to store the line number. ;) Once I read your pointers, I quickly came to the last code sample myself. I just have `#{i+1}` for the line number.

Comment: The last bit of code really should be at the top.  That's ruby-way structure, and the OPs initial code is just due to their early learning.

Answer (score -1):

I am reading the book aswell and I came up with the following solution,

```
File.read('text.txt').split(/\n/).each do |t| 
  p t if t =~ /bleh/
end
```

Which I think is very nice. I am however also a Ruby-rookie. :)

Comment: You did not review the code.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].